# Multiple uitableview in a viewcontroller give an error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a problem with the following code that manage two uitableview in a viewcontroller. When insert the data in a modal controller in the 'directionTableView' give a follow error:

> **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**
>   'Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1059e7560) to 'FoodTime.DirectionRecipeTableViewCell' (0x101388bf0). 2018-05-23 21:50:12.160281+0200 FoodTime[4577:360265] Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1059e7560) to 'FoodTime.DirectionRecipeTableViewCell' (0x101388bf0).'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if (tableView == self.ingredientTableView)
    {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newIngredientCell", for: indexPath) as! IngredientRecipeTableViewCell

        let ingredientCell = ingredients[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = ingredientCell.titleIngredientRecipe
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ingredientCell.subtitleIngredientRecipe
    }
    else if (tableView == self.directionTableView)
    {
        //Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on next line
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newDirectionCell", for: indexPath) as! DirectionRecipeTableViewCell                 
        let directionCell = directions[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = directionCell.directionSection
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = directionCell.directionText
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: 1. Which line exactly is causing the error? 2. What is the complete, useful, human readable part of the error?

Comment: Typically, it will be beneficial to have one TableView per class. That's not to say that one view cannot have multiple TableViews, but you can delegate the table view's delegate and dataSource to separate controllers. This will probably save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Remove `IBOutlets` of both tableView and add again from storyboard or XIB

Comment: @maddy: i have edit the code ad insert the comment in the error line. This is the complete error message: 'Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1059e7560) to 'FoodTime.DirectionRecipeTableViewCell' (0x101388bf0).
2018-05-23 21:50:12.160281+0200 FoodTime[4577:360265] Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1059e7560) to 'FoodTime.DirectionRecipeTableViewCell' (0x101388bf0).'

Comment: @Davide that's because the var in the top of the function

Comment: @Alec: the uitableview are manage as extension. When insert the data in the ingredientTableView all works fine. When insert the data in the directionTableView the app crash...

Comment: Please make sure you have set the cell’s custom class to `DirectionRecipeTableViewCell` in InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: @Tom E: I love U!!! I have lost the link to class. Now Work very Good!!!

Answer (score 0):

Away from the problem the first line

```
var cell = UITableViewCell()
```

is actually what is being returned cells inside the if statements are local variables

So try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

        if (tableView == self.ingredientTableView)
        {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newIngredientCell", for: indexPath) as! IngredientRecipeTableViewCell

            let ingredientCell = ingredients[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = ingredientCell.titleIngredientRecipe
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ingredientCell.subtitleIngredientRecipe

             return cell
        }
        else  
        {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newDirectionCell", for: indexPath) as! DirectionRecipeTableViewCell //Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

            let directionCell = directions[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = directionCell.directionSection
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = directionCell.directionText

            return cell
        }

}
```

Also make sure that you register every tableview with the corresponding cell

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem causing the crash. It fixes other issues and adds a new one.

Comment: Sh_Khan: thx so much for your support. I have fix the problem... :)

Comment: Yes, the comment at the end of the answer will fix the base cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

error i so easy

you declare this

```
var cell = UITableViewCell()
```

then you create new one

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newIngredientCell", for: indexPath) as! IngredientRecipeTableViewCell
```

just remove `let`

Also

In interface builder  make sure that cell with `newDirectionCell` is `DirectionRecipeTableViewCell` and same for another cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if (tableView == self.ingredientTableView)
    {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newIngredientCell", for: indexPath) as! IngredientRecipeTableViewCell

        let ingredientCell = ingredients[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = ingredientCell.titleIngredientRecipe
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ingredientCell.subtitleIngredientRecipe
    }
    else if (tableView == self.directionTableView)
    {
        //Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on next line
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newDirectionCell", for: indexPath) as! DirectionRecipeTableViewCell                 
        let directionCell = directions[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = directionCell.directionSection
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = directionCell.directionText
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the crash.

Comment: he should make sure that cell with `newDirectionCell`  is `DirectionRecipeTableViewCell`   and same for others one

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish: yes, you right! I have lost the link to class... Thx so much!